# WSO2 Carbon Studio 1.0 crash when too many artifacts

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I have developing a WSO2 carbon app with Eclipse. When I have too many artifacts, components... eclipse crashes.

It seems to be related to handling too many artifacts by the root-artifact.xml interface. In fact, if eclipse crashes when it is opened I fail to re-open eclipse since just start just closed. The error it shows is

```
An internal error has occurred.
No more handles
```

I am using Eclipse Helios with Carbon Studio 1.0. It happens the same to some coworkers. I may have about 40-50 elements in the project. I have increased the memory up to 756 in the eclipse.ini. It shows like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
756M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
756m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx756m
```

Any help?

Comment: Post the contents of your error log ? Should be inside `WORKSPACE_HOME/.metadata/.log`

Comment: I've got the following differents errors:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-08-08 14:40:09.457
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4109)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-08-08 14:49:35.667
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles))
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)

Answer (score 0):

According to the provided information in here, issue is in your Operating system. It seems the  Eclipse process as ran out of file handles assigned to the process.

In this case, best thing is to close all the unwanted files/Editors in Eclipse and try to increase the operating system file handle limit.

It seems the [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=42986) issue is related to your scenario. Try [the following article.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx) It might be helpful but I have not tried out by myself.